# SQL joint and group simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- r1 with primary key k1.
- r2 with secondary key k1 (from r1 table) duplicate authorized.

r2 can therefore have several lines having k1 as secondary key, on which a sum could be therefore prformed.

Examples:

```
r1 = 
(NationalID| Name | Surname | Age)
(9854512| Smith| Ben     | 27)
(5454544| Khan | Michel  | 29)
(...................)

r2 = 
(DrivingPenaltyNumber | NationalID | DrivingPenaltyValue           )
(1                    |9854512     | 10                            )
(2                    |5454544     | 5                             )
(3                    |9854512     |                               )
(..................................................................)
```

I want to join these two tables, in one table that contains two columns: the primary key k1= NationalID , the number of occurences of k1 in r2 (the number of Driving penalties for each person), the sum of a given variable in r2 (the sum of penalties in $ for every person), and then filter the lines that have an accumulated penalty higher than a boundary. So, I want to make a join, group, conditioning operations simulatenously without creating an intermediate table. Would that be the correct and optimal solution ?

```
select r1.NationalID, count(r2.NationalID) as numberOfPenalties, sum(r2.DrivingPenaltyValue) as totalPenalty
from r1 
left join r2
on r1.NationalID= r2.NationalID
group by r1.NationalID
having count(r2.DrivingPenaltyValue) > boundary
```

Also, Is it possible to use where instead of having ? and how ? Could you please help and possibly provide references.

Comment: Your query is fine.  What is your question?

Comment: I think you meant `having sum(r2.DrivingPenaltyValue) > boundary` instead of  `having count(r2.DrivingPenaltyValue) > boundary`

Comment: Yes, indeed, the query works (after replacing count by sum in the last line). But I want to understand if it's possible to do that using where instead of having in the last line ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, then you don't actually need to join with `r1`. You can get the number of occurrences of each key over a threshold by using `GROUP BY`, `COUNT()`, and `HAVING`. I'll just store a threshold in a variable. You can make it whatever you want.

```
SET @threshold = 10; /* you can change this */

SELECT k1, COUNT(1) num_occurrences FROM r2 GROUP BY k1 HAVING num_occurrences > 
@threshold;
```

You could `LEFT JOIN` back to `r1` after doing the query above in order to find the keys over / under the threshold.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an example of the tables to make the question more clear. Indeed, I need to join the tables because I need to add some columns from the first table. So how can I add join in the same query (for the example above)?